# How to set viewing orientation of an android app

Tags: android

I am a first time app developer and I want to know how to make the phone show my app as landscape.
Sorry, I couldnt find out how :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your `<activity>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`
and add
`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`